# Laravel SQL Query Keeps Giving SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL query in my controller at laravel

```
$distinct_course = DB::table('student')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, MONTH(`student_date_ended`)'))
    ->where('student_course', '=', 'Basic Computer')
    ->whereYear('student_date_ended', '=', '2015')
    ->groupby(DB::raw('MONTH(`student_date_ended`'))
    ->get();
```

Which is based on this SQL query I made to work first before converting it to Laravel

```
select count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, MONTH(`student_date_ended`) from `student` where `student_course` = "Basic Computer" and year(`student_date_ended`) = 2015 group by MONTH(`student_date_ended`)
```

But for some reason I always get this error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, MONTH(`student_date_ended`) from `student` where `student_course` = Basic Computer and year(`student_date_ended`) = 2015 group by MONTH(`student_date_ended`)

Am I doing something wrong here that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, in all my projects I use the following way of DB interactions:

```
$Query = 'select count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, 
  MONTH(`student_date_ended`) 
  from `student` 
  where `student_course` = ? 
  and year(`student_date_ended`) = ? 
  group by MONTH(`student_date_ended`)';

$GradStudents = DB::select($Query, [ $StudenCourse, $StudentDateEnded]);
```

This way I can go from confirmed working MySQL statement to Laravel without worrying of call not working after conversion.

Note: Instead of keeping your db calls in the controller, I would them to a model folder. This way you will maintain the MVC design pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still getting used to Laravel so I still have to learn about how to use models in my project.

Comment: @Paul: I tried your scenario, but i got `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column` I can't be able to select multiple values in select('') if i use group by, any idea how to fix it??

Answer (score 0):

With Paul's help I managed to get it working with this code.

```
$Query = 'select count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, 
              MONTH(`student_date_ended`) as Month 
              from `student` 
              where `student_course` = ? 
              and year(`student_date_ended`) = ? 
              group by MONTH(`student_date_ended`), student_course';

  $StudentCourse = 'Basic Computer';
  $StudentDateEnded = 2015; 

  $distinct_course = DB::select($Query, [ $StudentCourse, $StudentDateEnded]);
```

It would seem that part of the problem was **I also needed to add the 'student_course' column in the group by** so I tried adding it to my original Laravel code and also managed to get it work with this manner.

```
 $distinct_course = DB::table('student')
    ->where('student_course', '=', 'Basic Computer')
    ->whereYear('student_date_ended', '=', '2015')
     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as grad_count, `student_course`, MONTH(`student_date_ended`) as Month'))
    ->groupby(DB::raw('MONTH(`student_date_ended`), student_course'))
    ->get();
```